# Magento 2.4.6-p3 wont save configs in backend after installing module

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I installed goeasyship/shipping by running

```
composer require goeasyship/shipping
```

After the installation, I try to add new configuration settings in the backend and they won't save. I thought it was related to app/etc/env.php but it isn't.

I am trying to add the new configuration settings in

Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > General > Store Information

I disabled the module and the error persists.

I don't know if I broke it by doing something else either.

If anyone has any tips I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the extension using the below the commands and check extension work or not.

```
composer require <component-name>:<version> 
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: That answer's not really related to the issue decribed. I used composer to install the module, but like I said configs on the backend won't save after installing.  I ran the update and upgrade commands